# Evento onclick em imagem

Tags: javascript, html, css

Existe alguma maneira de colocar um evento onclick em imagem?
Testei com um botão e está funcionando a chamada para a função, porém, queria usar uma imagem.

Tentei algo como:

```
<a href="#">
   <img src="imagens/search.png" onclick="ocultaForm()">
</a>
```

Porém, não está executando a função ocultaForm(), só redireciona para #

Comment: Por que vc não faz assim: `<a href="#" onclick="ocultaForm()">` ?

Comment: @hugocsl tentei, mas não executa a função

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para funcionar do jeito que você esta tentando, basta remover o atributo `href` da tag `a`, e lógico que a função de existir caso contrário não funcionará!

```js
var clicks = 1;
function ocultaForm() {
  alert('VOCÊ CLICOU NA IMAGEM!');
  if (clicks === 1) {
    console.log('Você clicou ' + clicks + ' vez na imagem!');
  } else {
    console.log('Você clicou ' + clicks + ' vezes na imagem!');
  }
  clicks++;
}
```

```css
a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
img {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<a>
   <img src="http://www.voluntersul.com.br/editor/Image/clickaqui.png" onclick="ocultaForm()">
</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

O [onclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) funciona perfeitamente em um elemento `<img>`, o problema é que sua imagem está contida em um `<a>`, então quando você clica é executado o click no `link`.

Segue exemplo:

```js
function ocultaForm(){
  console.log("Oi mundo!");
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.google.com.br/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png" onclick="ocultaForm()">
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.thumbnails').click(function() {
            alert('teste');
           // ocultaForm(); pode chamar aqui
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="../images/bottle.jpg" alt="bottle" class="thumbnails" />
```

```js
function ocultaForm(){
    alert();
}
```

```html
<img src="../images/bottle.jpg" alt="bottle" class="thumbnails" onClick="ocultaForm()" />
```

Comment: Poderia [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/273767/edit) sua resposta e explicar ela ? Para o **AP** entender aonde estava o erro.

Comment: O problema é que sua imagem está dentro de em um  link toda vez que clica no link ele executa o link..

Answer (score 0):

tirando o link você conseguiria fazer assim:

```
<img src="imagens/search.png" onclick="ocultaForm()" style="cursor:pointer"/>
```

Comment: Não executa a função.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    function teste(){
      console.log('fui clicado');
   }
```

```html
  
  <img src="https://www.google.com.br/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png" onclick="teste();"/>
```

Tente assim e veja se é o que você precisa.